# Regex to test character length of a string

Tags: regex

How do I test to see the length of a string using regex?

For example, how do i match a string if it contains only 1 character?

Comment: What language? Why can't you use a proper function like `length()` or `strlen()`?

Comment: `/^.$/`, but I can't believe whatever language you're using doesn't have a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^.$
```

But most frameworks include methods that will return string length, which you should use instead of regex for this.

Comment: The `{1}` is really extraneous and just adds line-noise.

Comment: $ also can match newline, so the re would match "x" and "x\n"

Comment: @Seth In what regex flavor does `$` match after a newline? The OP didn't mention an application. In JavaScript, for example, `/foo$/.test("foo\n")` returns `false`.

Comment: @Phrogz: No, the point is it matches *before* a newline and end of line.  As for what regex flavors, System V, POSIX, Perl, Ruby, PHP, Python are the ones I know of.  I'm not actually aware of any that do not work that way.  Well, I wasn't until I saw your javascript example.

Answer (score 4):

Anchor to the start and end of string and match one character. In many languages:

```
^.{1}$
```

In Ruby's Regex:

```
\A.{1}\z
```

Comment: The {1} doesn't add anything.  The latter is correct while the former will match "x" and "x\n".  You also need to ensure that . can match \n, which it often will not without the /s modifier (/m in Ruby)

Comment: @Seth The `{1}` doesn't add anything in the "for example" case mentioned by the OP, but the OP asked for how to test the length in general. I've added the {1} (as have others) to make it clear how to match a different number of characters. Further, whether or not `$` matches after a "\n" depends on the regex flavor. As the OP has not yet specified the flavor, your statement is not absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Matching a single character would be (using Perl regex):

```
/\A.\z/s
```

`\A` means "start of the string", `.` means "any character", and `\z` means "end of the string". Without the `\A` and `\z` you'll match any string that's longer than one character.

**Edit:** But really you should be doing something like:

```
if( length($string) == 1 ) {
  ...
}
```

(using Perl as an example)

**Edit2:** Previously I had `/^.$/` but, as Seth pointed out, this allows matches on strings that are two characters long where the last character is `\n`. The `\A...\z` construct fixes that.

Comment: The listed regex will match "x" and "x\n"

Comment: Except . typically means "any character but \n" unless you use the /s modifier (/m in Ruby), so "\n" would not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^.\z/s
```

The above requires perl compatible regexps.  The trick is that /^.$/ might match "x" and "x\n".  Adding /s modifier doesn't help there.